# Class constructor compiles on clang but rejected on gcc

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, language-lawyer, copy-constructor

I am learning about constructors in C++. In particular, that a C++ class can have more than one constructor. But then I made the following program that worked with clang but not with gcc and msvc.

```
template<typename T>
struct A {
    A() {}
    A(A<bool>);  
};
A<bool> a;    //works with clang but not with gcc and msvc
//A<double> b;  //works with all compilers
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/434xhvY76)

Surprisingly `A<bool> a;` works only with clang and is rejected by gcc and msvc but `A<double> b;` works with all of the 3 compilers.
MCVC says:

```
<source>(4): error C2652: 'A<bool>': illegal copy constructor: first parameter must not be a 'A<bool>'
<source>(4): note: see declaration of 'A<bool>'
<source>(6): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'A<bool>' being compiled
```

Why are we getting this error and which compiler is correct according to the C++ standard.

Comment: Looks like ill-formed(NDR perhaps?) since `A<bool>` is incomplete in the parameter declaration `A(A<bool>);`

Comment: @Jason That's irrelevant. A function parameter's type is not required to be complete in the function's declaration, only in its definition.

Comment: @user17732522 But then why [this](https://godbolt.org/z/Kdb6j968Y) doesn't compile.

Comment: @Jason Because of the rule quoted in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to the C++20 Standard (11.4.5.3 Copy/move constructors)

> 5 **A declaration of a constructor for a class X is ill-formed if its
> first parameter is of type cv X and either there are no other
> parameters or else all other parameters have default arguments.** A
> member function template is never instantiated to produce such a
> constructor signature.

So when the type template argument is `bool`  for an instantiation of your template  class then in fact you have the following constructor in that class instantiation

```
A( A );
```

And the error message

> (4): error C2652: 'A': illegal copy constructor: first
> parameter must not be a 'A'

points to this produced ill-formed copy constructor for the instantiation of the class `A<bool>`.

On the other hand, when the type template argument is `double` (or something else) then this declaration of the constructor

```
A( A<bool> )
```

for such an instantiation of the class does not produce an ill-formed copy-construtor because for example types `A<double>` and `A<bool>` are two different class types.

To avoid the error it will be enough to declare the constructor in the class template as

```
template<typename T>
struct A {
    A() {}
    A(A<bool> &);  
};
```

Comment: `A` is not a class in OP's question. It's a class template. Your quoted statement talks about class not class template.

Comment: @Jason The instantiation of A<bool> is a class.

Comment: Your quoted statement talks about a class and not a class template.

Comment: @Jason As I already wrote an instantiation of a class template is a non-template class is not it?

Comment: The question is however how that rule is supposed to apply to templates. That does not seem obvious to me at all. There really is syntactically only one declaration for the constructor of the template, not one for each instantiation.

Answer (score -1):

The program ill-formed no diagnostic required. This can be seen from [temp.res](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.res):

> The validity of a template may be checked prior to any instantiation.
> [ Note: Knowing which names are type names allows the syntax of every template to be checked in this way.
> — end note ] The **program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required**, if:
>
> - a **hypothetical instantiation of a template immediately following its definition would be ill-formed due to a construct that does not depend on a template parameter,** or
> - **the interpretation of such a construct in the hypothetical instantiation is different from the interpretation of the corresponding construct in any actual instantiation of the template.**...

Comment: Not my -1, but arguably it does depend on a template parameter.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat But `A<bool>` is non-dependent.

Comment: The last highlighted section is part of a note. It is not normative. The relevant normative part is the one you didn't highlight and it talks about differences between instantiations (one of them hypothetically after the template definition). The hypothetical instantiation of `A<bool>` would be fine, since `A<bool>` doesn't have to be complete in it. The note is overly broad and just says that scenarios with that property exist where the rule applies, not that the rule applies to every scenario with that property.

Comment: @user17732522 So are you saying it is not IFNDR? This looks IFNDR to me due to the first highlighted bullet point.

Comment: @Jason Either the rule from [class.copy.ctor] doesn't apply and the program is well-formed or it does apply to the instantiation and then it is ill-formed and the only question is whether it is IFNDR. I think is is more likely not to apply interpreting the exact wording, although it is probably intended to apply. I guess one could argue that technically a hypothetical instantiation of `A<bool>` would be ill-formed in the latter case due to a non-dependent construct, so that it is IFNDR. But that wouldn't really be intended I would say. [temp.res]/5 doesn't seem well-worded to me.